# Is it possible to run more than one Turing Machine emulator using only one processor kernel?

Tags: turing-machines, computer-architecture, os-kernel

I had this question on computer architecture exam and can't find an answer anywhere.
**Is it possible to run several Turing Machine emulators at once using only one processor kernel?**
*a)* Yes, by executing the instructions of every machine in turns;
*b)* No;
*c)* Yes, but you need to use OS threads.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.  Don't leave important information only in the title.  Don't leave important information in the comments.  Tell us what your thoughts are and what prevents you from answering it yourself.  What do you think?  Can you think of any way to do it?  Can you think of a way to run a single Turing machine emulator?  Do you have any specific doubts?  We want to help you understand concepts, but just answering exercise-style questions for you might not achieve that in a useful way.  I encourage you to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: If a, b and c are indeed the answer choices in an exam, that would be pretty annoying. Because c, as stated is wrong (as the correct a shows). So either the examiner meant the correct "Yes, by using OS threads" and messed it up, or it is a trick question, and I couldn't decide which one.

Comment: I'm sure he meant "by using OS threads".

Comment: @CoderGirl I have given up guessing what people mean many years ago.

Comment: Who gives such silly questions on exams? "Yes, because a single processor kernel, whatever that is, is Turing complete."